# Как перезапаковать объект в json для записи в бд?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, json, woocommerce

Есть сайт на `wordpress` в котором мне нужно извлечь из бд информацию по цене **$totalprice**, сделать с ней необходимые мне преобразования и обновить данные в бд.

Данные хранятся в объекте `json` и декодировать я их могу, но вот с обратным процессом перекодировки у меня возникает проблема.

Поможете?

```
global $wpdb;
foreach ( $getcart as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
//извлекаю данные
$reservations = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM '.$DOPBSPWooCommerce->tables->woocommerce.' WHERE cart_item_key="%s" AND token="%s" AND product_id=%d', $cart_item["key"], $cart_item["dopbsp_token"], $cart_item["product_id"]));
$js = json_decode($reservations[0]->data);
$totalprice = round($js->price_total,2);
}
$totalprice+= 100;

//как поместить $totalprice внутрь $data и закодировать?
//обновить данные
$wpdb->update($DOPBSPWooCommerce->tables->woocommerce, array('data' => $data),
array('cart_item_key' => $cart_item_key, 'token' => $values['dopbsp_token'], 'product_id' => $values['product_id']));
```

Comment: И проблему мы должны угадать?

Comment: @u_mulder Так я же описал проблему с перекодировкой, которая и в названии вопроса фигурирует и внутри кода
`как поместить $totalprice внутрь $data и закодировать?`
Сложность в том, что `$reservations[0]->data` это изначально закодированный json объект с кучей папарметров

Comment: А что такое `$data` и где она определяется?

Comment: `$data` это просто будет измененный закодированный json объект внутрь которого хочу поместить измененный `$totalprice`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как данные полученные из БД находятся в объекте `$js`, то надо сделать следующее:

```
$js = json_decode($reservations[0]->data);
$js->price_total += 100;
```

Теперь в `$js` поле `price_total` увеличено на 100. 
Далее надо закодировать объект `$js` обратно в json:

```
$jsStr = json_encode($js);
```

И передать полученную строку `$jsStr` в запрос на обновление, вероятно (т.к. не работал с woocommerce) как-то так:

```
array('data' => $jsStr)
```